# Incorrect number of parameters for function 'ISPICKVAL()'. Expected 2, received 3

Tags: workflow, picklist

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want when first s1 Milestones check box true and apply for submit for approval after approval history show in 3rd image approved link click last image click approve button then stage change from stage 1 to stage 2 from workflow

```
IF(
      AND(
         S1SD1__c = true, 
         S1SD2__c = true, 
         S1SD3__c = true,
         ISPICKVAL(ApproveStatus__c, 'Ready for Approval'),
         ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Stage 2 - Needs Identified & Accepted',"")
      )
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Why "" in the end of 2nd ISPICKVAL?

Comment: yes ISPICKVAL is wrong also your IF condition is also wrong  `IF(condition, true, false)`. this is the structure.. Please details in your question what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
IF(
     AND(
        S1SD1__c = true, 
        S1SD2__c = true, 
        S1SD3__c = true,
        ISPICKVAL(ApproveStatus__c, 'Ready for Approval'),
        ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Stage 2 - Needs Identified & Accepted')
     ),
     "output if true",
     "output if false"    
)
```

This should fix your error.

- For starters, your IF was wrong (you only added the condition)
- Secondly, your second ISPICKVAL has 3 parameters, while only 1 is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

**Change**

```
ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Stage 2 - Needs Identified & Accepted',"")
```

**TO**

```
ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Stage 2 - Needs Identified & Accepted')
```